# Select MIN and MAX Date and their adjacent columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with a need for a query. 
I have a Table that has +/- this structure

```
RowNo  Event     Cty     Ctry     Arrival               Departure
  1      LL     Cty_B   Ctry_B   2017-07-04 06:00:00   2017-07-04 06:30:00
  2      LL     Cty_A   Ctry_A   2017-07-04 07:00:00   2017-07-04 07:30:00
```

What I need from this, is

```
RowNo  Event     Cty     Ctry     Arrival               Departure
  1      LL     Cty_B   Ctry_B   2017-07-04 06:00:00   2017-07-04 07:30:00
```

Pretty basic stuf you might say, but i can't find a solution

If i use GROUP BY  I just can't include Cty and Ctry because that'll result in two different records.
if I use MIN or MAX apply to the Cty and Ctry, in this example MIN will give me the wrong data since it chooses the alphabet order "Cty_A", and some of you might say "Use MAX Then" But the problem is I do not know what alphabetic order the Cty and Cry are, so if I use MAX and Cty_A is on the firt row,then MAX will choose Cty_B

any thoughts?

Comment: Why RowNo 1?...

Comment: Of course I don't understand the requirements, but I do not know why you would want to include Cty_B and Ctry_B in the result set, when the Arrival and Departure values (MINs and MAXes) do not necessarily apply to the city and country.  Are you sure you need them?

Comment: Is it correct that you want the arrivaldate from record 1 and the departure date from r2 ?

Comment: also what happens when you have multiple rowno,event

Comment: What is unique about these two rows which you understand them to be linked? Can you add more rows to your example with expected output?

Comment: @Mihai: Because it is the row with the min arrival date

Comment: @VinceI I need the first city and the first ctry

Comment: @FrederikGheysels it is! to get the interval between them

Comment: @scsimon the is another field : OrderNO, that field links them

Comment: @TheGameiswar that is an example of multiple rowno events

Comment: Well you need to list orderno in the example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your grouping column, but i think you are looking query like below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(order by RowNo),
          MinArrival = min(arrival) over(),
          MaxDeparture = Max(departure) over()
      from yourtable ) a
   Where a.RowN = 1
```

If you want to include grouping column then include it in RowN as Row_Number() over (Partition by yourgroupingcolumn order by RowNo) and include the same partition by in min and max if you require min and max for specific group

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the data from the min RowNo and add the max Date to it.

```
;with cte as --This will return the aggregates you want
(
select min(RowNo) as RowNo
   , event
   , MIN(Arrival) Arrival               
   , MAX(Departure) Departure
from table
group by event 
)
select t.RowNo
   , c.event
   , t.Cty
   , t.Ctry
   , c.Arrival
   , c.Departure
from table t
 join cte c on c.RowNo=t.RowNo
```

Comment: If OrderNumber is the link than switch out my group by but you didn't make that clear in the question. I had to assume it was event.